# Get the title of another page in PmWiki

Tags: php, page-title, pmwiki

I have a valid page name that I need to resolve to a page title. Example:

### Main.TargetPage

```
(:title Page One:)
I am the page of which the title needs to be got.
```

### Main.CurrentPage

```
(:title Example Page:)
I am the page that the PHP script is being run from.
```

How can I get the title of `Main.TargetPage` from `Main.CurrentPage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the title of a page with this function call:

```
$PageTitle = PageVar(ResolvePageName('Main/TargetPage'), '$Title');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the other's page title by command **{Main.TargetPage$Title}**, see official [docs](https://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/PageVariables):

Comment: This is useful, but it's a PmWiki markup solution, not a PHP solution.